What is the oxidation state of Fe in the complex $\ce{[Fe(NO)2(CO)2]}$?
I was tasked to evaluate the Sidgwick's EAN for the Fe centre in $\ce{[Fe(NO)2(CO)2]}$. The solution states the answer to be 36 and says that the oxidation state of Fe in the complex is -II and the ligand is $\ce{NO+}$.
However, the source appears outdated for it also states that Fe exists as $\ce{Fe^I}$ in the brown ring complex. And seeing the answers to the query Is iron in the brown ring compound in a +1 oxidation state?, I think the characterization of the metal centre and ligand would be better made as $\ce{Fe^{II}}$ and $\ce{NO-}$, but I could not locate any studies or research data, being largely unfamiliar with academia as a high-school student.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-innocent_ligand
